# freemarker evaluates expression but doesn't display value

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm sending a bean to a freemarker page, the bean has a field of type object:

```
${myBean.myObject.DDate}
```

When I use this expression I'm sure that the value being evaluated since when I placed a break point in `myObject.getDDate()` method the debugger got there, the problem is that the expression string is what being displayed as an output:

```
${myBean.myObject.DDate}
```

When I try `${myBean.myObject} myObject.toSring()` is being displayed correctly

Comment: I managed to fix this, in case somebody in the future faces something like this, it looks like freemarker doesn't output the date as it is(?), once I added a format to the date it worked : ${myBean.myObject.DDate?string("yyyy-MM-dd")}

Comment: FreeMarker prints dates according the `date_format` setting, or if it's not sure how to format the date then it throws an exception. It doesn't just print nothing. So either the `date_format` was somewhere set to an empty string there, or there was an exception but FreeMarker was set up to use a `TemplateExceptionHandler` that just prints nothing then.

Answer (score 0):

`${myBean.myObject.DDate}` may throw exception, if myObject or DDate is null, so to be safe side first check it, then get value form it as following

```
<#if myBean.myObject.DDate}??>

// you need to get it as ?string(data_time_format_goes_here)

date:${myBean.myObject.DDate?string("yyyy-MM-dd")}
date:${myBean.myObject.DDate?string("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")}

//FreeMarker also contains different built-ins for formatting dates
date:${myBean.myObject.DDate?time}
date:${myBean.myObject.DDate?date}
date:${myBean.myObject.DDate?datetime}

</#if>
```

FreeMarker also contains different built-ins for formatting dates http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html

Update Works only with the latest version of FreeMarker [2.3.17](http://freemarker.org/docs/versions_2_3_17.html) , You see changes on Changes on the FTL side and server side, even you can set date time format via configuration object

```
//config.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
//config.setDateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
```